# excute action before dialog dismiss

Tags: android, android-dialog

How to make a way to perform action before Dialog dismiss in android, I'm setting it to cancel on outside touch `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` but I want to execute some action before the dialog is being dismissed, as `setOnCancelListener` and `setOnDismissListener` methods are invoked after the dialog is dismissed.